# Add a button and a webbrowser in a scrollviewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a scrollviewer that contain a webbrowser, I need to add a button  `<Button Grid.Row="1">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/cont_banner.png" />
                            </Button.Background>
                            <Button.Content>
                                <HyperlinkButton Content="" NavigateUri="callto:3950" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>`
 also inside the scrollview but i can't.

This my code with the button outside the scroolviewer, how can i move it inside?

```
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="25, 0, 0, 0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Descrption}" Style="{StaticResource servicesText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />-->

                        <phone:WebBrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}" x:Name="webBrowserHTML" Foreground="Black" Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />

                    </ScrollViewer>
                        <!--<Image Source="../Images/cont_banner.png" Width="270"  Grid.Row="1"/>-->

                    <Button Grid.Row="1">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/cont_banner.png" />
                        </Button.Background>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="" NavigateUri="callto:3950" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>


                </Grid>


            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Margin="25, 0, 0, 0">
    <StackPanel>
        <phone:WebBrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}"
                          x:Name="webBrowserHTML"
                          Height="400"
                          Foreground="Black"
                          Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />

        <Button>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/cont_banner.png" />
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Content>
                <HyperlinkButton Content="" NavigateUri="callto:3950" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note that **you'll need to set the height of the web Browser control explicitly to something appropriate**.

You probably also want to set that left margin to be 24 pixels (not 25) to be consistent with the rest of the platform.

**Update**
You MUST set the height of the `WebBrowser` for this to work.

Comment: If i add a stackPanel, the binding of the webbrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}"
 don't work??

Comment: @user1428798 Updated answer: The binding does work as the loaded event fires. It just defaults to a height of zero. You MUST set the height of the control to be able to see it