# binding error in Xaml windows phone

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

if i use this code:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="25, 0, 0, 0"
              Grid.Row="0">
  <phone:WebBrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}"
                    x:Name="webBrowserHTML" Foreground="Black" 
                    Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I can bind the datacontext of the webbrower with the discription but when i add a stackpanel like this, the binding failed!!

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="25, 0, 0, 0"
               Grid.Row="0">
   <StackPanel>
     <phone:WebBrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}"
                       x:Name="webBrowserHTML" Foreground="Black"
                       Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />
   </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Any solutions please??

Regards

Comment: Please note how I formatted your code. Please do so in future questions yourself.

Comment: Is the property actually named `Descrption`? It looks like there is an `i` missing...

Comment: the property name is descrption without i. in the first simple without the stackpanel the binding is ok but when i add the stackpanel the binding failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Ref [Add a button and a webbrowser in a scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438144/add-a-button-and-a-webbrowser-in-a-scrollviewer)

If the binding fails the loaded event won't fire. Is that the case or does the event fire but nothing be displayed? I suspect the latter.

The issue is that the `StackPanel` does not have in inherent size and so it does not know how big to draw the `WebBrowser`. You can address this by setting an explicit Height of the WebBrowser control that you want to render.

```
<StackPanel>
    <phone:WebBrowser DataContext="{Binding Path=Descrption}" 
                      x:Name="webBrowserHTML" Foreground="Black"
                      Height="1000"
                      Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The problem is a problem of binding! the binding of DataContext Failed

Comment: @user1428798 if the binding is failing what is the exception it's reporting? See the output windows when the page opens in debug to see the message